# PdfSharp, combine several pdf pages and put text on top of combined pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I want to combine several single pdf pages to one pdf, and at the same time put a number on the top of the FIRST page. Somekind of a watermark, but aligned top, left.

Anyone know how this can be solved?

Right now I got the following code to merge the files:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Merging started.....");
    PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
    foreach (string pdfFile in pdfFiles)
    {
        PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;

        foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
        {
            outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
        }
    }
    outputPDFDocument.Save(outputFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Merging Completed");
            addOverlay(outputPDFDocument);
```

EDIT:
I made it work by opening the combined document after the save, and then adding text.

```
    public static void addOverlay(PdfDocument combined_pdf)
{
    PdfDocument document = combined_pdf;

    // Select the first page
    PdfPage page = document.Pages[0];

    page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;

    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XPageDirection.Downwards);

    // Write on top of background with known colors
    gfx.DrawString("TEXT ON PDF PAGE", new XFont("Helvetica", 12, XFontStyle.Regular), XBrushes.White, 10, 0, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

    // Save the new modified document...
    document.Save("final_path");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the best way, but I know two ways that will surely work:

1. Do it like the PDFsharp sample Two Pages on One does (only modified to One Page on One)
2. After saving the file (as you do now), you can open it for modification and add the text to the pages (see the Watermarks sample that comes with PDFsharp)

Method 2 keeps the pages as they are. With method 1 you have to pay attention to different page sizes in the source files - but you also have the chance to scale all pages to a single format (e.g. DIN A4) which could be more user-friendly than a file with several different page formats.

Comment: Thanks. Posted the solution above.